# Java to python conversion

Tags: java, python

I'm looking for the best way to Pythonize the: for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by pythonize?

Comment: You should read on basic python programming in general.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you seen [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) yet? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are iterating over the items in some container, just iterate over that container; don't use the index unless you need to.

Right:

```
slots = [1, 2, 3, 7]
for slot in slots:
    print cards[slot]
```

Wrong (or at least "writing C/C++/Java/C#/whatever in Python"):

```
slots = [1, 2, 3, 7]
for i in range(len(slots)):
    print cards[slots[i]]
```

If you need an index for some other purpose (e.g. you're going to modify the container), the Python way is `enumerate()`:

```
for i, slot in enumerate(slots):
    print cards[slot]
    slots[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A Python equivalent loop:

```
for i in range(0,itemsCount):
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) is the relevant section of the documentation (it was the first result on a google search for "python loop", by the way).

In python 2.x

```
for i in xrange(itemsCount):
  # rtfm
```

In python 3

```
for i in range(itemsCount):
  # rtfm
```

***note:*** A vanilla `range` will work in python 2.x as well, but it's inefficient because it builds the iterable list in memory which is unnecessary for the common use case of building loop structures.

***note2:*** If the only thing you will use `i` for is to index into some container, it is more pythonic to simply iterate over the container, e.g. `for item in my_list:`.  If you need the index aswell for some reason, the usual way is to iterate with `for i,v in enumerate(my_list):`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't know, you can use the enhanced for loop in Java

```
for(String str : array){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear. To me, it seems like he wants to use python syntax inside of java. That is why I suggested the enhanced for loop.